# Can you set a future publish date in Google Play?

Tags: google-play, release, publish

I know you can set a future release date (post date) in the Apple App Store and Amazon App Store.  Is this possible within Google Play?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it ii for Google support.

Comment: Can we still not set a future publish date in Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to set a future release date (publishing date) on Google Play. Please feel free to share your suggestion in the official [Android Development community on Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/105153134372062985968).

Comment: Can we still not set a future publish date in Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like google recently added this feature to their platform. It is called 'Timed Publishing'.

To enable it simply navigate to the 'APK' section for your app and look for the 'Timed Publishing' button on the top right.