# Does Google Playstore allow us to set a future date when publising/updating an app?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, release-management, autorelease

I did see a similar question but wanted to check if something has changed since then.

[Can you set a future publish date in Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18454371/867591)

I know we can upload an app and then manually publish it at a later date. But is there an option to schedule this so that it executes automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has not changed. You ***can*** use the [Publshing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing) to do it programatically. If you can incoporate other code to schedule when you run the calls for the Publshing API, theoretically, you may be able to accomplish "setting an upload time." However, uploading the apk requires it to go through some processing and reviewing which can take up to 24 hours (usually just a few hours), so you won't be able to get an exact time.